# eshell print time and exit status for every command

Tags: eshell

`fish` shell (and `zsh`) let you register commands that run before and after every command.

I have my shell configured to print the exit status if nonzero and the amount of time taken to execute the command in seconds if longer than 10 seconds.

Here's an implementation of that behavior in `fish`

```
# ~/.config/fish/config.fish

# set a global variable to the current epoch time in seconds
# before executing any comment
function get_start --on-event fish_preexec
    set -g cmdstart (/bin/date '+%s')
end

# inspect previous exit status, write "Exit n"
# where n is a non-zero exit status
function show_exit_status
    switch $status
    case 0
        true
    case '*'
        echo "Exit $status"
    end
end

# compute the time in seconds since the command was started.
# print it if the time exceeds 10 seconds
function show_time_consumed
    set taken (math (/bin/date '+%s') - $cmdstart)
    if math $taken '>=' 10 >/dev/null
        printf 'Time: %ss\n' $taken
    end
end

# show the time consumed and the exit status
# after the command is run
function postcmd --on-event fish_postexec
    show_exit_status
    show_time_consumed
    echo
end
```

And an example of what it does

```
> sleep 14
Time: 14s

sleep 14; /bin/false
Exit 1
Time: 14s
```

I'm trying to figure out how to emulate the same behavior in `eshell`.

Here's my initial attempt to port it:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-echo-area-message "USERNAME")
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

(defvar eshell-current-command-start-time (float-time))

(defun eshell-current-command-start ()
  "store the current starting time"
  (setf eshell-current-command-start-time (float-time)))

(defun eshell-current-command-stop ()
  "write the stopping time"
  (let ((the-time (float-time)))
    (message (number-to-string
           (- the-time eshell-current-command-start-time)))))

(add-hook 'eshell-pre-command-hook #'eshell-current-command-start)

(add-hook 'eshell-post-command-hook #'eshell-current-command-stop)
```

It has some problems that hamper its usefulness.

- When you hit enter after an empty command, the `post-command-hook`
  runs, but the `pre-command-hook` does not.
- Neither `message` nor `print` write to the `eshell` buffer.

Is there a straightforward way of grabbing the time using `float-time` before and after every command executes (including empty commands) and displaying it in the buffer the same way that the output of a command would be displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my attempt

```el
(defvar-local eshell-current-command-start-time nil)

(defun eshell-current-command-start ()
  (setq eshell-current-command-start-time (current-time)))

(defun eshell-current-command-stop ()
  (when eshell-current-command-start-time
    (eshell-interactive-print
     (format "Time: %.0fs\n"
             (float-time
              (time-subtract (current-time)
                             eshell-current-command-start-time))))
    (setq eshell-current-command-start-time nil)))

(defun eshell-current-command-time-track ()
  (add-hook 'eshell-pre-command-hook #'eshell-current-command-start nil t)
  (add-hook 'eshell-post-command-hook #'eshell-current-command-stop nil t))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook #'eshell-current-command-time-track)
;; To uninstall
;; (remove-hook 'eshell-mode-hook #'eshell-current-command-time-track)
```

Test it with some simple commands in Eshell

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~ $ sleep 3
Time: 3s
~ $ date && sleep 1
Sat Jul 14 20:52:18 2018
Time: 1s
~ $
```

Comment: adding `(when eshell-current-command ...)` to `eshell-current-comand-stop` seems to do the trick for suppressing time information when the command is empty.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet `eshell-current-command-stop` also needs to reset `eshell-current-command` to `nil`, I have updated the code.

Comment: The question also mentions the exit code of the last command. Any idea how to get that? (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/66879/10090)

Comment: @ZelphirKaltstahl `eshell-last-command-status`, I believe it works for external command such as /bin/grep, but doesn't work for Emacs Lisp commands such as grep/cd/dired.

Comment: @xuchunyang Thanks for that! For me it does `Symbol’s function definition is void: eshell-last-command-status`. I don't want to escalate these comments into a conversation. If you  post it as an answer, I could comment on that and perhaps check as correct answer.

Comment: @ZelphirKaltstahl The variable is only defined in the eshell buffer.

Comment: @xuchunyang If I add it in my `init.el` for my `eshell-prompt-function` though, I cannot access it and it gives the error about `Symbol’s function definition is void: eshell-last-command-status`.

Comment: Because this is a variable and not a function