# eshell last exit code in prompt

Tags: eshell, prompt

My Emacs version is:

`GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0)`

I have modified my eshell prompt as follows:

```
(defun set-eshell-prompt-function ()
  (setq eshell-prompt-function
        (function
         (lambda ()
           (concat
            (propertize (format-time-string "%H:%M:%S" (current-time))
                        'face
                        `(:foreground "#A0A0A0"))
            "::"
            (propertize (user-login-name)
                        'face
                        `(:foreground "#FF9080"))
            "@"
            (propertize (let ((sys-name (system-name)))
                          (let ((sys-name-len (length sys-name)))
                            (if (> sys-name-len 8)
                                (concat (substring sys-name 0 8) "...")
                              sys-name)))
                        'face
                        `(:foreground "#FF9080"))
            "::"
            (propertize
             (let ((limit 36)
                   (loc
                    (if (string= (eshell/pwd) (getenv "HOME"))
                        "~"
                      (eshell/pwd))))
               (let ((loc-length (length loc)))
                 (if (> loc-length limit)
                     (concat "..." (substring loc (- loc-length limit)))
                   loc)))
             'face
             `(:foreground "#FF9080"))
            "$ "))))
  (setq eshell-highlight-prompt t)
  (setq eshell-prompt-regexp "^[^#$\n]*[#$] "))

(set-eshell-prompt-function)
```

However, I would like to also see the last command's exit code in the prompt. I could not find the appropriate procedure to call to get it.

How can I get the last exit code, so that I can put it into the prompt?

## Edit

At hint of the comment by Marioba, I have tried the following:

```
(propertize (concat "[" (number-to-string $?) "]")
                        'face
                        `(:foreground "#A0A0A0"))
```

But unfortunately that does not work and results in the following error output in the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
concat: Symbol’s value as variable is void: $\? [2 times]
reference to free variable ‘$\?’
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `$$` or `$?` variables. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#:~:text=%24%24,on%20successful%20completion).

Comment: @Marioba Unfortunately that does not work, because these variables are not defined in the context of `init.el`. I edited my post to include the attempt. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `eshell-last-command-status` variable?

```lisp
(setopt eshell-prompt-function
        (lambda ()
          (concat (abbreviate-file-name (eshell/pwd))
                  (if-let ((status eshell-last-command-status))
                      (if (= status 0) "" (format " [%s]" status)))
                  (if (= (user-uid) 0) " # " " $ "))))
```